# How can I detect whether or not a browser is mobile and display a video at different sizes with javascript "if else"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, detection

So I need to include javascript and jquery in my html page that will check whether visitors are using mobile browsers, and display a video at different sizes depending accordingly.

I've tried several ways of doing this, but have yet to find something that actually works.

What I need is something like:

```
if (isMobile()) {
   //display larger
else {
   //display smaller
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!('ontouchstart' in window)) {
  // is desktop
  elVideo.src= 'desktop.mp4';
} else {
  // is mobile
  elVideo.src= 'mobile.mp4';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I don't actually have 2 different sizes for the video. is there anyone to do by resizing?

Answer (score 0):

You can detect like this

```
    if(jQuery.browser.mobile)
    {
       //code to be executed when device is mobile
    }
    else
    {
       //code to be executed when device is not mobile
    }
```

Comment: Just a heads up, the jQuery.browser method was deprecated and removed in jQuery 1.9. View the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/)